# Determine Operating System from PL/SQL

Tags: windows, command-line, plsql, java-stored-procedures, return-code

I am using the PL/SQL Package OS_COMMAND (which itself uses Java) to execute shell commands. I can observe their return codes.

I want to determine whether I am operating on Windows or any other operating system.

I've come up with different approaches:

- My first idea: execute a specific Windows command (which should
  always be successful) and check the return code: 0 means Windows,
  anything else means other OS.
- Using a Java Stored Procedure
- Using database information, for example

  - `SELECT platform_id, platform_name FROM v$database`
  - `SELECT dbms_utility.port_string FROM DUAL`
  - `SELECT NAME FROM v$dbfile` and check the format

Which one would you consider the "safest"? Do you use other approaches? What are advantages/disadvantages?

I'd like to avoid the Java Stored Procedure, and I don't know exactly how to interpret the database information (how to systematically check for Windows: result containing 'WIN' or 'Windows', or ...?). If you'd check with a specific Windows command, which one should I use?

I'll be glad about advice in any direction.

Comment: what you are trying to do? what do you want is OS name for DB or Client?

Comment: If the DB is running on Windows, I want to do _x_, else I want to do _y_.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat late response but anyway here are my two cents.

I agree with you that it seems best to get the information directly from the database environment to avoid unnecessary calls between "environments". So that brings us directly to the 3 mentionned options:

1. v$database: well you can rely on the information and from that point of view this seems a pretty "safe" solution. On the downside, you will need at least select privilege on the underlying table for this to work and that might be an issue in certain environments.
2. dbms_utility.port_string: no worries about privileges here but than again you don't get as much info as with option 1. Please also keep in mind to only use this for OS determination and not oracle version.
3. v$dbfile: well this is a deprecated view so first of all better to use v$datafile. But then comes in an important downside with this approach: what are you going to do when ASM is used? If I'm not mistaken the name format is the same on all OS platforms when using ASM.

Cheers

Björn